# Create a column that is the average of some other columns in a table -SQL

Tags: ssms

My database contains a table thats contains some columns like:
`C1 int, C2 int, C3 int`

I want to add another row in my table which contains the average of this three grades:

```
ALTER TABLE Avg:
ADD COLUMN ...??
```

but I want to this column (Avg) only compute average of C1, C2 and C3 when they are not null.

for example for a row C1 Value is 2 ,C2 value is null and C3 value is 3, then Avg must be (2+3) / 2
or in another row C1 value is 4 ,C2 value is 5 and C3 value is 6, then Avg  must be (4+5+6) / 3
Thanks.

Comment: For sql server you can create a computed column, like: `ALTER TABLE sometable ADD avgsomething AS (ISNULL(C1, 0) + ISNULL(C2, 0) + ISNULL(c3, 0)) * 1.0 / NULLIF((ISNULL(c1 * 0 + 1, 0) + ISNULL(c2 * 0 + 1, 0) + ISNULL(c3 * 0 + 1, 0)), 0)` although there's probably a simpler way

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer might be product specific. Don't waste other people's time writing answers for "wrong" dbms.)

Comment: @jarlh I think the ssms tag strongly tips the balance towards sql server over mysql for this specific question... but yes, it is still ambiguous.

Comment: @siggemannen you should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE (table_name)
ADD average_column FLOAT;

UPDATE your_table
SET average_column = (isnull(c1,0) + isnull(c2,0) +isnull( c3,0))*1 / 3;
select * from marks
```

hope you will get your score in SQL

Comment: `/ 3` won't work cause it should only count non-null values

Comment: And you should recommend a computed/virtual column. Storing calculated values like this too often ends up with data inconsistency.

Comment: And float might not be the best choice of data type...

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**